# Different certificate subjectAltName on same site with different scheme

Tags: php, ssl, ssl-certificate

Hee,

After a lot of trial and error to read certificates data to display the information. My use case is google.nl to read the certificate with chains.

My current issue is the difference between different scheme on the google domain results on different subjectAltNames. What i wan't to fix is a code to read the same certificate information as browser gives on display certificate information details on every website i requested.

My current testcode:

```
<?php
$url = "https://www.google.nl";
$orignal_parse = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
$get = stream_context_create([
        "ssl" => [
            'capture_peer_cert' => true,
            'capture_peer_cert_chain' => true,
            'disable_compression' => true
        ]
    ]);
$read = stream_socket_client("ssl://".$orignal_parse.":443", $errno, $errstr, 30, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $get);
$cert = stream_context_get_params($read);
$certinfo = openssl_x509_parse($cert['options']['ssl']['peer_certificate']);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($certinfo);
```

The result of subjectAltNames in the code above is;

> [subjectAltName] => DNS:*.google.com, DNS:*.android.com, DNS:*.appengine.google.com, DNS:*.cloud.google.com, DNS:*.db833953.google.cn, DNS:*.g.co, DNS:*.gcp.gvt2.com, DNS:*.ggpht.cn, DNS:*.google-analytics.com, DNS:*.google.ca, DNS:*.google.cl, DNS:*.google.co.in, DNS:*.google.co.jp, DNS:*.google.co.uk, DNS:*.google.com.ar, DNS:*.google.com.au, DNS:*.google.com.br, DNS:*.google.com.co, DNS:*.google.com.mx, DNS:*.google.com.tr, DNS:*.google.com.vn, DNS:*.google.de, DNS:*.google.es, DNS:*.google.fr, DNS:*.google.hu, DNS:*.google.it, DNS:*.google.nl, DNS:*.google.pl, DNS:*.google.pt, DNS:*.googleadapis.com, DNS:*.googleapis.cn, DNS:*.googlecommerce.com, DNS:*.googlevideo.com, DNS:*.gstatic.cn, DNS:*.gstatic.com, DNS:*.gstaticcnapps.cn, DNS:*.gvt1.com, DNS:*.gvt2.com, DNS:*.metric.gstatic.com, DNS:*.urchin.com, DNS:*.url.google.com, DNS:*.youtube-nocookie.com, DNS:*.youtube.com, DNS:*.youtubeeducation.com, DNS:*.yt.be, DNS:*.ytimg.com, DNS:android.clients.google.com, DNS:android.com, DNS:developer.android.google.cn, DNS:developers.android.google.cn, DNS:g.co, DNS:ggpht.cn, DNS:goo.gl, DNS:google-analytics.com, DNS:google.com, DNS:googlecommerce.com, DNS:source.android.google.cn, DNS:urchin.com, DNS:www.goo.gl, DNS:youtu.be, DNS:youtube.com, DNS:youtubeeducation.com, DNS:yt.be

If you change $url to https://google.nl the result of the subjectAltNames will change to;

> [subjectAltName] => DNS:*.google.nl, DNS:google.nl

What i like to get is the right result same as the browser information displays when you clicked on the certificate information details.

On OSX in Safari browser you see the list of the first result.

Thanks!

Comment: `https://www.google.nl` and `https://google.nl` are different URLs with different hostnames. Each one can reply with its own set of certificates. So there is no right or wrong result, the result depends on the URL you query. Be careful about HTTP redirections too: second URL redirects to first one, so you have to follow the possible chain of redirections if you want to have the end results as in a browser.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Thanks for your explanation. stream_socket_client don't follow the redirections but no problem. Thanks!